# Unable to pass on a CGFloat parameter in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the code below

```
- (void) scaleWithXFactor: (CGFloat) x andY: (CGFloat) y {
    [self.drawing passWithX: x anyY: y];
}
```

I get the following error

```
Sending CGFloat to parameter of type CGFloat*
```

How am I supposed to pass the cgfloat to the next method ?

Answer (score 4):

CGFloat is a value type. CGFloat* is a reference (pointer) to a CGFloat value.

You need to get a reference to your float. This is easy using the ampersand operator.

```
&x
```

Gives you a reference to x. So in your particular case:

```
- (void) scaleWithXFactor: (CGFloat) x andY: (CGFloat) y {
    [self.drawing passWithX: &x anyY: &y];
}
```

As rmaddy mentioned in comments below, if you don't have a good reason for passWithX to take references (pointers) as its parameters, then don't have it take references. Change its arguments from (CGFloat*) to (CGFloat).

Comment: yes, I thought as much. Although, while I called the "scaleWithXFactor" I did not send a &var. I just the var

Comment: That's because your scaleWithXFactor function's parameters are (CGFloat), not (CGFloat*).

Comment: @PrakashRaman For future readers, it would help if you added the declaration of the `passWithX:anyY` to the question.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the `passWithX:andY:` method is needlessly defined with `CGFloat *` instead of just `CGFloat`.

Answer (score 0):

Please add header file `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` to you .m file.